# How to find app causing error messages in MacOS 13.1 (Ventura)?

Tags: macos, app

I get an error message that app "Maowen Liu" tries to install background parts of software. When I look ar the startup background I can find "Maowen Liu", and I disabled disabled it. The error message keeps popping up. I was not able to find the app "Maowen Liu" (which looks like a developer).

How can I find what app to uninstall to get rid of this?

[image: error message]

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue with Ventura itself. For some reason it is not listing apps by name but by developer. The only way to trace it is to see what apps they make & whether you have a match.

Googling "Maowen Liu" it seems they did make apps for the App Store, but no longer. Searching by developer gives no match. See - https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254324734

CNet also lists some apps for iOS by the same developer. https://download.cnet.com/developer/maowen%20liu/i-10339442/

Ventura 13.2 was released a few days ago - they may have fixed this issue.